# How can I communicate Search and Tabs?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn flutter. My app has two tabs (With TabController). 
And one Search view at AppBar.

I tried to communicate tabs but could not get a result yet.

Here is myTabs and tabController;

```
final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
  new Tab(text: "First"),
  new Tab(text: "Second"),
];

TabController tabController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  activeSearch = false;
}
```

and appBar:

```
 return AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: randomHint(),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => activeSearch = false),
          )
        ],
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      )
```

I could not communicate search view and tabs yet.

Comment: I wrote a post about widgets communication: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: @diegoveloper thanks, i looked at your example but how can i communicate tabs if they were different classes?

Comment: I'm using different classes in my example : https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter-samples/tree/master/lib/communication_widgets